# How to pass a parameter once for multiple select

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I am currently trying to declare a parameter with which I can use it in several select, when I try to launch the current query it puts me several errors in particular :

> **PLS-00103:** Encountered the symbol "end-of-file" when expecting one of the following

Do you have an idea or guide me to the right voice, please?

```
declare
 Bon  NUMBER(20) := &1; --Example : 12345678
begin
 select * 
   from BonTable
  where BonChamp = Bon
    and BonChamp2 = 'FBON'
    and BonChamp3 is not null;

 select * 
   from BonTable2
  where BonChamp4 = Bon
    and rownum = 1;
end;
```

I would like this to ask me my parameter then execute both select, currently it asks me the parameter but it sends me back to error

Comment: doing selects inside anonymous blocks makes little sense in oracle. If it was a stored procedure with output parameters of `sys_refcursor` type, it would make sense. You're not gaining any transactional integrity. Your editor already tracking your DML and you have to issue `commit` explicitly. so, if you call these `select`s together or separate - makes no difference. Oracle simply doesn't support `select` within code block. Only `select into` and as part of cursor. There is a way though to print ref cursor in Sql Plus https://docs.oracle.com/cd/A81042_01/DOC/sqlplus.816/a75664/ch35.htm

Answer (score 4):

if you do a select in plsql, you shoul use `into` clause.
e.g. when your select Statements return always only one row you can declare a variable of type rowtype of your table: `BonTable%rowtype`.

if your select Statement return more than one row, you should  declare a table type of `BonTable%rowtype`.

```
declare
 Bon  NUMBER(20) := &1; --Example : 12345678
 rec1 BonTable%rowtype;
 rec2 BonTable2%rowtype;
begin
 select * 
   into rec1  
   from BonTable
  where BonChamp = Bon
    and BonChamp2 = 'FBON'
    and BonChamp3 is not null;

 select * 
   into rec2 
   from BonTable2
  where BonChamp4 = Bon
    and rownum = 1;
end;
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I understand a little better the usefulness of rowtype, by cons I tried with but it seems that dbvisualizer does not recognize it
ORA-00900: Invalid SQL Statement

Comment: i have tested it  here *db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=a8d8ba2a5ba2b07e1e6015cbfa17cf2a)* and i don't see your exception. I do not see what you are doing exactly. do you have a select statement after the plsql block? then you have to add a `/` behind `end `